# In beamer, how to use \pause inside \only

Tags: beamer, pause

I want to use `\pause` inside `\only` as in the example below. Sometimes it works well (see slides 2 and 3), but sometimes it doesn't (see slides 5 and 6). Why?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \hfill \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{An example}
\only<1>{
insert a picture for instance
}
\pause
\only<2-3>{
\begin{itemize}
\item here is my first remark
\pause
\item and here is my second
\end{itemize}
}
\only<4>{
insert a 2nd picture
}
\pause
\only<5-6>{
\begin{itemize}
\item bla bla bla
\pause
\item ...
\end{itemize}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

On purpose, I want the footline to display the number of frames, that is only "1/1" in this example.

Comment: I believe omitting the `\pause` before `\only<5-6>` should help. _(Ok, I just found it doesn't work. I'm afraid that as the manual says `\pause` cannot be mixed with `<n->` syntax.)_

Comment: @tohecz thanks, but then why does it work on slides 2 and 3? Otherwise, would you know another way of doing it?

Comment: See my answer. If it does not work, let me know, I might look into it more tomorrow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't have my LaTeX here, but this ought to work. You have to rewrite each `\pause` to proper `<n-m>` syntax.

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{An example}
\only<1>{
insert a picture for instance
}
\only<2-3>{
\begin{itemize}
\item<2-3> here is my first remark
\item<3-3> and here is my second
\end{itemize}
}
\only<4>{
insert a 2nd picture
}
\only<5-6>{
\begin{itemize}
\item<5-6> bla bla bla
\item<6-6> ...
\end{itemize}
}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 23):

This is due to the way that `\pause` works.  As `beamer` processes a frame, it has an internal counter `beamerpauses` which it uses to work out what the current "logical" slide is.  This is for use when you want to specify an overlaid command without referring to a specific slide, which is useful if you don't know (or haven't yet decided) what the specific slide number is.  It is used when you have things like `\item<+->` or `\alert<.(1)>`.  It is incremented according to strict rules: basically, you need a `+` in the overlay.  It is **not** incremented by things like `\alert<3-4>`.  This is useful as it allows you to have a "main flow" (using `+`) and some things outside it, using explicit specifications.

Now the punchline.  `\pause` is the same as `\onslide<+->`.  So it uses the `beamerpauses` counter and increments it.  But all those `\only`s don't.  Moreover, when the overlay specification for `\only` is **not** matched, it throws away its contents without processing it.  So those `\pause`s inside `\only`s are not processed when the overlay is not matched.

Let's consider what happens on slide 5.

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{An example}
\only<1>{% not present on slide 5
insert a picture for instance
}
\pause % on slide 5
\only<2-3>{% not on slide 5
\begin{itemize}
\item here is my first remark
\pause % not on slide 5
\item and here is my second
\end{itemize}
}
\only<4>{ % not on slide 5
insert a 2nd picture
}
\pause % on slide 5
\only<5-6>{ % on slide 5
\begin{itemize}
\item bla bla bla
\pause % on slide 5
\item ...
\end{itemize}
}
\end{frame}
```

Thus we are left with the following, and I'll count `beamerpauses`:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{An example} % beamerpauses = 1
\pause % beamerpauses = 2
\pause % beamerpauses = 3
\begin{itemize}
\item bla bla bla
\pause % beamerpauses = 4
\item ...
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

But we're on slide 5, so all of those pauses are considered as "dealt with" meaning that on slide 5, the entire contents are typeset.

There are various ways to fix this, but the simplest is to avoid mixing these two methods of specifying what goes on slides.  Use `\pause` for the main flow and only use specific specifications for things outside the main flow.  If all else fails, you can always manually set `beamerpauses` with a `\setcounter{beamerpauses}{5}`, for example.

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed answer, I understand much better now the internals of all these commands

Answer (score 1):

I often find that `\pause` doesn't behave like I expect it to do.  To me, `\pause` should, in all cases, show the text following it one slide after the current text.  I've implemented that as follows:

```
\makeatletter

\newcount\np@pauses
\np@pauses=\z@
\def\np@reset{%
  \loop\ifnum\np@pauses>\z@
    \csgundef{np@pause@\the\np@pauses}
    \global\advance\np@pauses by -1 %
  \repeat}

% At each frame, reset the \np@pause@ variables
\apptocmd{\beamer@reseteecodes}{\np@reset}{}{}

\newcommand{\np@pause}[1]{%
  \ifcsname np@pause@#1\endcsname%
    \beamer@@pause[\csname np@pause@#1\endcsname]%
  \else%
    \ifnum\beamer@coveringdepth=0 %
      \@tempcnta=\beamer@slideinframe%
      \advance\@tempcnta by 1 %
      \expandafter\xdef\csname np@pause@#1\endcsname{\the\@tempcnta}%
      \beamer@@pause[\the\@tempcnta]%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\newif\ifnp@patched
\let\np@beamer@frameslide\beamer@frameslide
\let\np@endbeamer@frameslide\endbeamer@frameslide
\RenewEnviron{beamer@frameslide}{%
  % Replace all \pause's by \np@pause{uniq-id}.
  \np@pauses=0%
  \loop%
    \global\advance\np@pauses by 1 %
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\np@pause{\the\np@pauses}}%
    \expandafter\patchcmd\expandafter{\expandafter\BODY\expandafter}%
      \expandafter{\expandafter\pause\expandafter}%
      \expandafter{\temp}%
      {\np@patchedtrue}{\np@patchedfalse}%
    \ifnp@patched%
  \repeat%
  \np@beamer@frameslide%
  \BODY%
  \np@endbeamer@frameslide%
}
\makeatother
```

This redefines the `beamer@frameslide` environment to change each `\pause` into `\np@pause{uniq-id}` where the uniq-id is simply the how many `\pause`s were read before.  Then `\np@pause` waits until it is executed in a visible way (`beamer@coveringdepth=0`), stores the current slide number, and acts as a `\pause[slide-nb + 1]` from that point on.

This uses `etoolbox` and `environ`.

Your example together with that snippet has the "expected" behavior.